# How do I convert string to datetime in ADF?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm transforming Rest data results and sink into Azure SQL and it fails with error below when translating string into DateTime2.

> "ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidDataValue,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Column
>   'ABOR_CDOM_Seed_Datetime' contains an invalid value
>   '2017-01-02T16:33:43.223Z'. Cannot convert '2017-01-02T16:33:43.223Z'
>   to type 'DateTime' with format 'yyyy-MM-dd
>   HH:mm:ss.fffffff'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=System.FormatException,Message=String
>   was not recognized as a valid DateTime.,Source=mscorlib,'"

Answer (score 6):

One has to go to `Schema` of sink and add `Format` as below to accommodate for this custom format

[image]

Comment: Thanks - this solved the exact problem I was experiencing too!

Comment: Thank you so much to clarify this small doubt. It was a blocker for me for 1 day.

Comment: I'm doing the same thing - going from a REST API to Azure SQL.  I have imported the schema, and I don't have nearly the same options that are shown above.  All of the fields show fixed values of "abc String" and then I can pick the target column from the database, but I don't see any "format" column.  How can I get this additional level of configuration?